# Reading files elsewhere in directory w/ Ruby

Tags: ruby, path

I've got a project structure as follows:

- info.config (just a JSON file w/ prefs+creds)
- main.rb
- tasks/

  - test.rb

In both main.rb (at the root of the project), and test.rb (under the tasks folder), I want to be able to read and parse the info.config file. I've figured out how to do that in main.rb with the following:

```
JSON.parse(File.read('info.config'))
```

Of course, that doesn't work in test.rb.

**Question**: How can I read the file from a test.rb even though it's one level deeper in the hierarchy?

Appreciate any guidance I can get! Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `JSON.parse(File.read('../info.config'))` work?

Comment: Do `File.read('./test.rb')`

Comment: @ArupRakshit OP wants to read `info.config` from within `test.rb` I think

Comment: @mu無 Ohkay.. I read it in reverse.. :)

Comment: @mu無, That will not work if working directory is not the `tasks` (the directory that contains `test.rb`)

Comment: +1 .. It is really a good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use relative path:

```
path = File.join(
    File.dirname(File.dirname(File.absolute_path(__FILE__))),
    'info.config'
)
JSON.parse(File.read(path))
```

- `File.dirname(File.absolute_path(__FILE__))` will give you the directory where `test.rb` resides. -> (1)
- `File.dirname(File.dirname(File.absolute_path(__FILE__)))` will give you parent directory of (1).

Reference: [`File::absolute_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-absolute_path), [`File::dirname`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-dirname)

**UPDATE**

Using [`File::expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path) is more readable.

```
path = File.expand_path('../../info.config', __FILE__)
JSON.parse(File.read(path))
```

Answer (score 4):

What I usually do is:

Create file called `environment` or similar in your project root. This file has only one purpose - to extend load path:

```
require 'pathname'
ROOT_PATH = Pathname.new(File.dirname(__FILE__))
$:.unshift ROOT_PATH
```

Require this file at the beginning of your code. From now on every time you call require, you can use relative_path to you root directory, without worrying where file you are requiring it from is located.

When using File, you can simple do:

```
File.open(ROOT_PATH.join 'task', 'test.rb')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do as below using [`File::expand_path`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path) :

```
path = File.expand_path("info.config","#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/..") 
JSON.parse(File.read(path))
```

- `File.dirname(__FILE__)` will give you the path as `"root_path_of_your_projet/tasks/"`.
- `"#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/.."` will give you the path as `"root_path_of_your_projet/"`. `..` means go one level up from the current directory.
- `File.expand_path("info.config","root_path_of_your_projet/")` will give you the actual path to the file as `"root_path_of_your_projet/info.config"`.

You can also use [`__dir__`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) instead of `File.dirname(__FILE__)`.

`__dir__` : *Returns the **canonicalized** absolute path of the directory of the file from which this method is called.*

Hope that explanation helps.